# Differences in checking if a variable is not empty with !empty

Tags: php

Is there a case where I will get a different result if I use `if ($somevar)`

instead of `if (!empty($somevar))`?

Aren't these two doing the exact same thing?

Comment: Sure. The variable may hold a value that _resolves_ to something falsy in php weak type logic. Whcih would make the first condition true. but the variable is _not_ empty.

Comment: Obvious difference would be you wont get `variable does not exist` warnings if `$somevar` does not yet exist when using `empty()`

Comment: The answer to your question is in the first table in the documentation page about [PHP type comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). The second and the last column tells that both statements (`if (! empty($somevar))` and `if ($somevar)`) have the same outcome but, as @RiggsFolly explains in their comment, `if ($somevar)` triggers a notice that `if (! empty($somevar))` doesn't trigger.

Comment: @arkascha read the documentation of [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). It doesn't follow the common sense and returns `TRUE` for things that are not considered to be "empty" in the real life. F.e., `empty("0")` is `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I understand the differences now. Also is my question not asked correctly that it got down voted? Should I have asked this on a different exchange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at all,

`if ($somevar)` – This generates a notice if `$somevar` is not set

`if (!empty($somevar))` – This is functionally equivalent to `if($somevar)`, but doesn’t generate a notice.

`empty()` does NOT produce E_NOTICE on undeclared variables